# Hide iframe or div from other iframe in a frame

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, frames

I am trying to show or hide a div containing a iframe from another iframe which contains a frameset.

So if you are looking in the code; I am trying to show or hide div "dd" with a function within shades.html. Shades.html is part of a frameset in index2.html which is shown in iframe "UBERFRAME" in index.html.

Some code:
Index.html:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
    <div style="display:block;position:absolute;top:20px;left:20px;z-index:997;">
        <iframe name="UBERFRAME" src="index2.html" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="yes" scrolling="no" style="width:800; height:480; position:relative; left:0px;top:0px;margin:0;padding:0;" ></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="dd" name="dd" style="position:absolute;top:20px;left:20px;z-index:998;">
        <iframe id = "overlayframe" name = "OVERLAY" src="dd.png" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="yes" scrolling="no" style="width:800px; height:480px; position:relative; left:0px;top:0px;margin:0;padding:0;" ></iframe>
    </div>
</BODY>
```

index2.html:

```
<HTML>
<FRAMESET ROWS="51,376,53,*" FRAMEBORDER="0" FRAMESPACING="0">
    <FRAMESET COLS="70,335,324,71,*" FRAMEBORDER="0" FRAMESPACING="0">
        <FRAME SRC="HEADER/home.html" NAME="homeheader" NORESIZE SCROLLING="no">
        <FRAME SRC="HEADER/name.html" NAME="nameheader" NORESIZE SCROLLING="no">
        <FRAME SRC="HEADER/datetime.html" NAME="datetimeheader" NORESIZE SCROLLING="no">
        <FRAME SRC="HEADER/help.html" NAME="helpheader" NORESIZE SCROLLING="no">
    </FRAMESET>

    <FRAME SRC="mainempty.html" NAME="mainframe2" NORESIZE SCROLLING="no" BORDER="0">

    <FRAMESET COLS="69,142,70,316,100,103,*" FRAMEBORDER="0" FRAMESPACING="0">
        <FRAME SRC="FOOTER/so.html" NAME="so" NORESIZE SCROLLING="no">
        <FRAME SRC="FOOTER/shades.html" NAME="shades" NORESIZE SCROLLING="no">
        <FRAME SRC="FOOTER/sendsource.html" NAME="sendsource" NORESIZE SCROLLING="no">
        <FRAME SRC="FOOTER/volume.html" NAME="volume" NORESIZE SCROLLING="no">
        <FRAME SRC="FOOTER/micmute.html" NAME="micmute" NORESIZE SCROLLING="no">
        <FRAME SRC="FOOTER/outmute.html" NAME="outmute" NORESIZE SCROLLING="no">
    </FRAMESET>
</FRAMESET>
```

shades.html:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showdd() {
            window.frames['overlayframe'].style.display = "none";
        }
    </script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <a href="#" onclick="showdd(); return false;" >
      <img src="foo.png">
    </a>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Or plunkr demo: [Click](http://embed.plnkr.co/yfafQr/)

Comment: Could you supply a jsfiddle or plunkr demo?

Comment: If you try to access parent elements from an iframe, you're gonna have some problems. How could your iframe be aware of what your parent window contains ? Instead of iframe, load your html in the page. Then you'll be able to access every "html file" DOM elements. (As an example, you can use jquery to load the page, or just to an XMLHttpRequest if you're not using jquery)

Comment: Hi Larta, I am very sorry, I don't know what you mean, my webprogramming skills is from what I can only describe, crappy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mate helped me fix the problem:

Index.html:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
  <script data-require="jquery@2.1.1" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function showDuck(){
      $('#dd').show();
      $('#overlayframe').show;
    }

    function hideDuck(){
      $('#dd').hide();
    }

  </script>
</HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <div style="display:block;position:absolute;top:20px;left:20px;z-index:997;">
            <iframe name="UBERFRAME" src="index2.html" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="yes" scrolling="no" style="width:800; height:480; position:relative; left:0px;top:0px;margin:0;padding:0;" ></iframe>
        </div>
        <div id="dd" name="dd" style="display:none;position:absolute;top:20px;left:20px;z-index:998;">
            <iframe id="overlayframe" name="OVERLAY" src="testframe.html" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="yes" scrolling="no" style="width:800px; height:428px; position:relative; left:0px;top:0px;margin:0;padding:0;" ></iframe>
        </div>

    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

index2 unharmed

shades.html:

```
<HTML>

<BODY>

     <a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.parent.parent.showDuck(); return false;">
         show Donald Duck
     </a>

</BODY>

</HTML>
```

testframe.html:

```
<HTML>
  <BODY>
    <IMG SRC="http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130203061323/disney/images/6/6b/Donald_Duck_transparent.png" onclick="javascript:window.parent.hideDuck(); return false;">
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Or http://plnkr.co/edit/x13V7l0qwv0jtI8IKXtf?p=info

Answer (score 1):

Are all three pages (parent documents and the two iframes) from the same domain and subdomain?

If not, your only real option is to use [window.postmessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage)

And even if they are from same domain, post message is good approach compared to directly accessing the DOM of another page.

Either way, with or without postmessage, You will need a reference to the window object of the iframe that you wish to target.

One approach is to have frame A inform the parent page (via raising event or calling a function in the parent page js), and then have the parent page inform frame B.

If you supply a example page I can create a working example for you.

EDIT: below code sample from the solution to the example that you provided.
notice how the frame is calling a function parent document. parent document then manipulates DOM of the other iframe.

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/cF4wW8WwZ9os1HiATLCF?p=preview)

in frame A:

```
 $('#show').click(window.parent.showDuck);
  $('#hide').click(window.parent.hideDuck);
```

in parent document:

```
 function showDuck(){

  $('#overlayframe')[0].contentWindow.document.getElementById('duck').style.setProperty('visibility', 'visible');
      }

    function hideDuck(){
  $('#overlayframe')[0].contentWindow.document.getElementById('duck').style.setProperty('visibility', 'hidden');

}
```

Comment: see the bottom of the page ;) I just created one in plunkr

Comment: Oh and yeah, its all part of one domain, no pages are located on another domain or so

Comment: Could you maybe please integrate it in my code? So that it works from within shades.html and name.html?

Comment: You are making the image hide, but I need the iframe or the div where the Iframe is part of to hide

Comment: I updated the plnkr to hide the whole iframe. http://plnkr.co/edit/cF4wW8WwZ9os1HiATLCF?p=preview   please study it and itegrate the solution within your code

Comment: there seem to be too many iframes in your code. I dont know what the logic is here. in any case, the donald duck image covers the buttons, so you cant click on them anyways. give it background-color and you will see:  http://plnkr.co/edit/uiIjnIFAj08bDHfKDgH0?p=preview